# How do you query exact match records with Views Filters, Entity References, and Taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

** Updated to keep the example consistent with the first paragraph. Using Taxonomy Terms, not the Taxonomies (term categories) themselves... based on Triskelion's comment **

How do you configure a Views Filter to return all users who have created at least one node with taxonomy term A “and” at least one node with taxonomy term B, where the taxonomy terms could be assigned to a single node or separate nodes?

Example:

**Users**
User1
User2
User3
User4

**Taxonomy Terms**
Taxonomy Term A
Taxonomy Term B
Taxonomy Term C
Taxonomy Term D

**Nodes**
NodeV -> created by User1 -> with Taxonomy Term A
NodeW -> created by User2 -> with Taxonomy Term A
NodeX -> created by User3 -> with Taxonomy Term C and Taxonomy Term D
NodeY -> created by User1 -> with Taxonomy Term B
NodeZ -> created by User2 -> with Taxonomy Term D

**Views Filter Results**
Show all users who have created a node with Taxonomy Term A
    Result: User1, User2
Show all users who have created a node with Taxonomy Term D
    Result: User2, User3
Show all users who have created a node with Taxonomy Term A and a node with Taxonomy Term D
    Result: User2

I currently have a view setup starting with Users and referencing the Nodes. I am having trouble making this work. Do I need to reverse the order and set the view for Nodes referencing the Users? Or am I barking up the wrong tree and should just jump to using Hooks?

Comment: Your first paragraph does not gibe with the rest of your question. To clarify, in a taxonomy, each Vocabulary is a collection of term. Are you looking to filter on individual terms, or are you looking for users who have created nodes using terms (any terms) from Vocabulary A AND Vocabulary B?

Comment: Good point, sorry for the confusion. I am referring to individual Taxonomy Terms not the Taxonomy (term collection).